# Not able to install PMD in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, pmd, eclipse-kepler

I have installed PMD in Eclipse Kepler using Eclipse market place.
But I am unable to access it after the installation.

When I go to Window → Preferences and search for PMD, I get no results.

Is there any other plugin available for source code cleanup?
Or: What needs to be done to install PMD in Kepler?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the PMD plugin that installs through Eclipse Marketplace to be harder to use than the standalone one.  Install available by an [Eclipse update site here.](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse/)

Answer (score 4):

I've tried all these suggestions and now i have it working in Kepler; here's how to do it:
I made sure my Eclipse Kepler instance was using Java 7--it was.

The link from the eclipse marketplace did not work.  It would show a PMD option for the individual projects properties, but there were no rules to select from.  Also the main workspace preferences were not showing up.

I had to install it using this update site, as Jeanne Boyarsky mentioned:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

Restart Kepler.

The PMD option now shows up in the Windows->Preferences->PMD

The PMD project menu now shows up when right clicking on the project.

Comment: Late 2015 update:  Just found that the same process is needed for Eclipse Mars. (The marketplace PMD install doesn't work all the way, and just shows a few menus but won't run PMD).

Answer (score 3):

The install information on the web site for this plugin http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/getting-started.html says you must open the `Properties` for a project and look at the `PMD` tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the PMD plug-in using the Eclipse market place then you're using eclipse-pmd which requires Eclipse to run on a JVM version 7 or later. If you're running Eclipse on a JVM version 6 or earlier and you're using eclipse-pmd 0.7 or earlier [the PMD property page won't be visible](https://github.com/acanda/eclipse-pmd/issues/6).

To solve this problem you have to run Eclipse on a JVM version 7 or later. To change the JVM on which Eclipse runs you have to set the parameter `-vm` in your eclipse.ini accordingly. The Eclipse Wiki explains how to [specify the JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

Comment: I have this problem in a new installation of Eclipse Kepler SR2 and eclipse-pmd 0.9. I'm running eclipse with Java 7.